# If $X=C(\mathbb{R}),\phantom{1}$ is $d(f,g) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n} \frac{d_n(f,g)}{1+d_n(f,g)}$ a metric over X?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I'm checking if the following expressions are metrics over  $X=C(\mathbb{R})$:

$$
d_n(f,g) = \sup_{x \in [-n,n]} \lvert f(x)- g(x) \rvert \phantom{3000000}  d(f,g) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n} \frac{d_n(f,g)}{1+d_n(f,g)}
$$

For the first one we can see that if we take :

$n = 1$

$f(x) = x$

$g(x) =\begin{cases}x & x \in [-1,1]\\x^3& \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $

$d_1(f,g) = \sup_{x \in [-1,1]} \left\lvert x- x\right\rvert = 0 \phantom{10}$ but $f \neq g $  so it is not a metric.

But I'm not sure how could I check the second one.

Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ because it isn't a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$. The functions $d_n$ are indeed not metrics, but your counterexample is wrong.

Comment: @Mark you are right.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a metric. Each $d_n$ is a pseudo-metric; more precisely, we don't always have $f\ne g\implies d_n(f,g)\ne0$ but, other than that every property of a metric holds for $d_n$. And so $2^{-n}\frac{d_n}{1+d_n}$ is also a pseudo-metric. Finally, if $f,g\in  C(\Bbb R)$ and $f\ne g$, take $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)\ne g(x)$ and take $n\in\Bbb N$ with $n\geqslant|x|$. So, $d_n(f,g)\ne0$ and therefore $d(f,g)\ne0$. Therefore, $d$ is indeed a metric.